# Dock icon not refreshing when icns file is changed on Yosemite

Tags: dock, icon, macos

I'm experiencing an issue where the Dock won't reload an icon I changed for one of my applications. I changed the icon by replacing the `.icns` file within the application package. The version I replaced it with is currently still there, but even after rebooting and killing the dock process multiple times, the old icon won't budge.

Strangely enough, I managed to change the icon for another app with no issue, following the same procedure and rebooting.

Are there any new gotchas with the way this works change in Yosemite? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to delete the icon cache:

```bash
rm /var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.dock.iconcache
rm -r /var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.iconservices*
killall Dock
```

Comment: This seems to work!

Comment: In Big Sur, I also needed to `rm -r /var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.iconservices*`

Comment: @hrunk's comment did it for me, but I had to run `killall Dock` afterward as well to get it to take effect